# Reverse WCF that will connect to a non .net tcpip application

Tags: wcf, tcp

I am new to .net and am trying to use c# as the basis of my .net learning. I have a project where I need a service to connect to mutliple tcpip applications that are a 3rd party application written in vb6. Someone has mentioned using WCF as the base, but i'm not sure how it would make an outbound connection (instead of receiving incoming ones) to a non .net application? Please help

Answer (score 0):

With C# and WCF, you can either create:

- a WCF **service** which will offer up some functionality that other applications can call

or:

- a **client** that connects to some other SOAP or REST service to consume functionality.

So which one is it you're looking for??

Also: WCF is a SOAP or REST based service stack - you cannot use it to connect to low-level TCP calls (socket programming). Your "other" side must understand either SOAP (the web service protocol) or REST (the URL-based lightweight protocol). If you other sides don't speak neither SOAP nor REST, you're out of luck and can't really use WCF for that.

Comment: ok looks as though i have been looking at the wrong this for what i need thatnk you both for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to deal with socket programming, WCF won't help you here.
Try reading this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsincsharp.aspx

Comment: ok looks as though i have been looking at the wrong this for what i need thatnk you both for your help

Comment: Are you sure Dimitry?, I have just been asked to research this topic and how to connect to TCP Server (console app, non NET)  broadcasting signal on particular port using WCF. Is it a mistaken defined requirements?